# Sending data in an email using python

Tags: python, email, scripting

I wrote this code and it runs normally whenever `public_ip` is not present in the final `msg` variable, but I want it to send with the email. Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

```
def send_email():
    import os
    import smtplib, ssl
    import requests

    login = os.getlogin()
    sys_info = os.getenv('os')
    ip = get_internal_ip()
    public_ip = requests.get('http://icanhazip.com').text.strip('\n')
    print(public_ip)
    print(ip)
    print(login)
    print(sys_info)

    port = 465  # For SSL
    email = input('Type your email and press enter: ')
    password = input("Type your password and press enter: ")

    # Create a secure SSL context
    context = ssl.create_default_context()

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", port, context=context) as server:
        server.login(email, password)
        server.sendmail(from_addr=email, to_addrs=email, msg=f'{login} | {sys_info} | {ip} | {public_ip}')

send_email()
```

Comment: You haven't said **what the actual problem is**.  Are you getting an error, or unexpected results, or what?

Comment: I am getting everything in the `server.sendmail` function except for the `public_ip`. I am not getting an error at all, I receive an email when `public_ip` is not included, or receive `None` when it is, in the place of where the variable output should be.

Comment: What do you mean "you receive None"?  You mean you do receive an email message, but the body content is just the word None ?